# How to configure stylelint to ignore folder but include part of that folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, stylelint

How could I exclude some folder from being ignored by stylelint?

Example I wand to ignore all folders and files in "styles" folder
except "styles/not_to_ignore/" folder and "styles/not_to_ignore/not_to_ignore.scss" file.

In gititnore config we could use special character to create and exclusion "!"

How to do this in "stylelintrc.json" config "ignoreFiles" section or somehow else?